# Como exibir dados num dbgrid

Tags: delphi, firebird

Estou usando `SQLConnection, SQLDataSet, ClientDataSet, DataSetProvider, ClientDataSet` e um `DataSource`.

Preciso exibir os dados num `dbgrid`, mas não estou sabendo como fazer isso.

No `FormCreate` eu devo abrir a conexão pelo `clientDataSet`?

```
procedure TFormImportDados.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  CdsFB.Open;  
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certifique-se de que os componentes esteja configurados corretamente:

**`SQLConnection`**: Configuração de drivers e caminho da base;

**`SQLDataset`**: Com um comando SQL válido, e com a Conexão definida como **`SQLConnection`**;

**`DatasetProvider`**: Propiedade `Dataset` definida como `SQLDataset`;

**`ClientDataset`**: Propiedade `ProviderName` definida como `DatasetProvider`;

**`DataSource`**: Propiedade `Dataset` definida como `ClientDataset`;

**`DBGrid`**: Propiedade `DataSource` definida como `DataSource`;

Feito isso basta dar um `.Open` no ClientDataSet:

```
ClientDataSet1.Open;
```

Obs.: Aconselho a dar o `.Open` no evento `FormShow`

Answer (score 1):

Eu não costumo rodar o projeto com os componentes abertos... Nesse caso eu abriria a conexão primeiro, depois o SQLDataSet, e depois o ClientDataset.
Eu acredito que tenha um CDS a mais aí... Minha recomendação seria utilizar `SQLConnection, SQLDataSet,DataSetProvider, ClientDataSet`  e, por fim o `DataSource`.